# Improving quicksort to sort in linear time?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, array-algorithms

Can we sort unsorted array of real numbers in linear time? 
This is what I am thinking :

Given an unsorted array of size n :

- Find out the `sqrt(n)^th` element using selection algorithm (call it x): O(n)
- Find out the smaller elements than x and larger elements than x and form 2 arrays : O(n)
- Sort the two arrays separately: O(sqrt(n)log(sqrt(n))) = O(n) as log(n) < sqrt(n)

So the whole algorithm is O(n)

I know that lower bound is nlog(n). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the third step, one of the arrays is O(sqrt(n)), but the other is still O(n - sqrt(n)) = O(n).

Comment: @MichaelLiu: that is the answer.